# Different div style for iPad/iPhone/Desktop

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad

```
<style>
// To show on laptop
#lala {
position: absolute; 
top: -520px; 
right:-250px;
}
// To show on iPhone
@media screen and (device-width:480px) {
#lala{
top:0;
}
}
// To show on tablets
@media screen and (device-width:768px) {
#lala{
top: 1;
right: 0;
}
}
</style>
<div id="lala">
[contactform]
</div>
```

I tried to switch with `max-device-width` and `min-device-with` but I couldn't get it right. 
I want to style the contactform different for each device, what I'm doing wrong?

So if width === 768px show the style between the `{ }` if width === 480px show the style between `{ }` else show the standard style.

Comment: Do you have this meta tag in your html?<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width/" >

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<style>
// To show on laptop
#lala {
position: absolute; 
top: -520px; 
right:-250px;
}
// To show on iPhone
@media (max-width: 480px) {
#lala{
top:0;
}
}
// To show on tablets
@media (max-width: 768px) {
#lala{
top: 1;
right: 0;
}
}
</style>
<div id="lala">
[contactform]
</div>
```

Make sure you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

inside the

```
<head></head>
```